# show printed messages inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

is it possible to see stdout (or log) T-SQL PRINT messages embedded in stored procedures when executed using sqlalchemy?

--edit--

It looks like pyodbc added a way to retrieve messages from a cursor for this very reason and it has been merged to master.  I still cant figure out how to get this to bubble up to sqlalchemy
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/pull/765#

--endedit--

I tried this adding echo=True to engine and setting a log level to debug but I can not see anything

this is how I am executing the usp

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger("sqlalchemy.engine")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
engine = sa.create_engine(target_uri, echo=True)
statement = sa.sql.text(f"EXEC {usp_schema}.{usp_name}")
with engine.begin() as cnxn:
    cnxn.execute(statement)
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_do_stuff 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
        PRINT 'DELETE STAGE'
        PRINT 'LOAD STAGE'
        PRINT 'CLEAN STAGE'
        PRINT 'TRANSPORT STAGE'
    END TRAN
END;
```

Comment: Related GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/495). There is a PR that has been merged into the master branch but it hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/pull/765

has only recently been merged (2021-01-21) and SQLAlchemy's `mssql+pyodbc://` dialect does not know anything about it yet. If you would like to see support for that feature added to SQLAlchemy then please open a feature request [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues).

In the meantime, the workaround is to install pyodbc from the current master branch …

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc.git
```

… and then use a `.raw_connection()` to execute the SP and retrieve the messages:

```py
"""existing stored procedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_do_stuff] 
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        PRINT 'DELETE STAGE'
        PRINT 'LOAD STAGE'
        PRINT 'CLEAN STAGE'
        PRINT 'TRANSPORT STAGE'
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
"""
cnxn = engine.raw_connection()
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("EXEC usp_do_stuff")
print(crsr.messages)
while crsr.nextset():
    print(crsr.messages)
"""
[('[01000] (0)', '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]DELETE STAGE')]
[('[01000] (0)', '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]LOAD STAGE')]
[('[01000] (0)', '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]CLEAN STAGE')]
[('[01000] (0)', '[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]TRANSPORT STAGE')]
"""
```